# Using lapply or map over columns to apply a McNemar test to all combinations of columns

Tags: r

I am trying to apply a McNemar test to different model combinations on my data. I have `N` models but here I show 3. I can do the following.

```
mcnemar.test(x = d$mod1, y = d$mod2)
mcnemar.test(x = d$mod1, y = d$mod3)
mcnemar.test(x = d$mod2, y = d$mod3)
```

I would like the results stored in a data frame such as:

P-value:

```
      mod1    mod2    mod3
mod1   -    0.1306   0.7518
mod2   -       -     0.3711
mod3   -       -       -
```

Data:

```
d <- structure(list(id = 1:50, mod1 = c("Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Incorrect", "Incorrect", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Incorrect", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Incorrect", "Correct", "Incorrect", "Incorrect", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct"), mod2 = c("Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Incorrect", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct"), mod3 = c("Correct", "Correct", "Incorrect", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Incorrect", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Incorrect", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Incorrect", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct", 
"Correct", "Correct", "Correct", "Correct")), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `outer` from `base R`

```
outer(d[-1], d[-1], FUN = Vectorize(function(x, y) mcnemar.test(x, y)$p.value))
#          mod1      mod2      mod3
#mod1       NaN 0.1305700 0.7518296
#mod2 0.1305700       NaN 0.3710934
#mod3 0.7518296 0.3710934       NaN
```

Or the same with a nested `sapply`

```
sapply(d[-1], function(x) sapply(d[-1], function(y) mcnemar.test(x, y)$p.value))
```

---

Or using `crossing/pivot_wider` from `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
crossing(v1 = names(d)[-1], v2 = names(d)[-1]) %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(pval = mcnemar.test(d[[v1]], d[[v2]])$p.value) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = v2, values_from = pval) %>% 
   column_to_rownames('v1')
#          mod1      mod2      mod3
#mod1       NaN 0.1305700 0.7518296
#mod2 0.1305700       NaN 0.3710934
#mod3 0.7518296 0.3710934       NaN
```

---

Or another option is to reshape into 'long' format and then do the `crossing`

```
d %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
    select(-id) %>%
    nest_by(name) %>% 
    crossing(., set_names(., str_c(names(.), '_new'))) %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    transmute(name, name_new, pvalue = mcnemar.test(data[[1]], data_new[[1]])$p.value) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = name_new, values_from = pvalue) %>%
    column_to_rownames('name')
#          mod1      mod2      mod3
#mod1       NaN 0.1305700 0.7518296
#mod2 0.1305700       NaN 0.3710934
#mod3 0.7518296 0.3710934       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just going to ask you for a tidyverse approach! :)

Comment: One question, how can I keep everything in a pipe. I am stuck at the part `d[[v1]], d[[v2]]` I have tried putting `.$[[v1]], .$[[v2]]` and using `%$%
  mutate(
    pval = mcnemar.test(., x = v1, y = v2) )`. It is not a major thing however.

Comment: @user113156 It is only because i started with column names in `crossing` and not the values, so, the `.` is the column names of 'd' and not the value from 'd'.

Comment: @user113156 there are multiple ways it can be done.  I updated with another option after nesting

Answer (score 1):

If you don't insist on storing it in the provided format, then one `dplyr` and `purrr` option could be:

```
map_dfr(.x = combn(names(d)[-1], 2, simplify = FALSE),
        ~ d %>%
         summarise(model = paste(.x, collapse = ", "),
                   p_value = mcnemar.test(x = get(.x[1]), y = get(.x[2]))$p.value))

  model      p_value
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 mod1, mod2   0.131
2 mod1, mod3   0.752
3 mod2, mod3   0.371
```